How to serialize and deserialize nested java objects when sending object to Kafka topics and receiving at consumer end using only Jackson
I am new to custom serialization/deserialization and also using it in Kafka is even more new for me. I am trying to explain what I am doing and also what I want to achieve. Please comment if you need more info.
I have a java object which contains reference to another object inside it and it also have reference to other objects. Also the referenced class is base class but we can receive instance of its subclass at runtime. For example B has many subclass in different packages and all these classes are from a jar file of 3rd party app which I have imported which means I cannot modify these classes.
Let's consider below sample as I could not post the real object:
class A {
    public String as1,
    public int ai2;
    public String as2;
    public B b;
 
   // getters & setters
}

Below is class B
class B {
   public String bs1;
   public C c;
   .
   . 
   // have around 42 fields
}

class C
class C {
   public String cs1;
   public String cs2;
   public String cs3;
   
   
}


At runtime it is using a subclass of B which is having around 100 fields including these 42 fields. For fields other than 42 which it is giving error: Unrecognized field "Somefieldname" and 42 known fields.
below is the more code :
Now I have written a custom serializer and deserializer:
Kafka Serializer
// serializer
ASerializer implements  Serializer<A> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, A data) {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            byte[] serialized = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
            //byte[] serialized = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            return serialized;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred ...");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Kafka Deserializer

// deserializer
ADeserializer implements Deserializer<A> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        jsonFactory.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES);
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public A deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        A respData = null;
        try {
            A deserialized = mapper.readValue(data, A.class);
            return deserialized;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


and in application.properties file:
####### PRODUCER ########
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=com.sample.serialization.ASerializer
spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.message.bytes=20971520
spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.request.size=20971520

####### CONSUMER ########
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=com.sample.serialization.ADeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.partition.fetch.bytes=20971520
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.fetch.max.bytes=20971520

During deserialization process I am getting error:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition test-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "SomeFieldName" (class com.sample.V8.B), not marked as ignorable (42 known properties: and 42 properties name)
NOTE: the field "SomeFieldName" is filed in child class of B not in B.
Please suggest me the solution so that I can deserialize each nested classes properly and form a main object as A (which has all the fields as before serialization).
NOTE: I only want to achieve this using Jackson only. do not want to use GSON of other.
I have tried below:
Tried creating above mentioned custom serializer and deserializer.
I am expecting:
I want to successfully serialize and deserialize my nested java object  using kafka and springboot

Spring-Kafka has a built-in JSONDeserializer. Did you try that instead? Are you sure this is a Kafka problem? Can you write a unit test that writes and reads your A class to/from bytes?

I have tried JsonDeserializer as well from spring-kafka but the issue is that inside my A class the the reference of B class gets object at runtime which may have values more that that declared in B class (as child cass has more values) and my requirement is that I do not want to ignore them rather wanted to deserialize them to the corresponding B's child and then set them in A.
